# 1,000 Miles North

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

<sup>This is an entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6352/48337).</sup>

---

This is the original xkcd's comic:

[image: xkcd]

here's an enjoyable song with similar title:

[A Thousand Miles - Vanessa Carlton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cwkej79U3ek)

and this is a similar comic to xkcd's:

[image]

*I admit it's not really similar, not even funny!*

So talking about distance:

> Find a similar man who's more than 1000 miles away.

Free clues:

> ignore that song,

**HINT 1**

> The song is not really part of the puzzle, you didn't need to listen to it, but there is a reason why I need to put it here at the beginning, and so also the original comic

**HINT 2**

> The title said this puzzle is about distance, if you look carefully in this post, you'll know what distance is being discussed

---

<sup>Sorry if there are many grammatical erros, I'm not a native english speaker and it was unintentional</sup>

Comment: You precised that the song is not a clue, but what about the original xkcd's comic, is it a clue? Because for now, it seems that people only found meaning in your own comic

Comment: I've put the original comic as a clue to answer the similar comic, but I think that part is solved now

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here, but

> The second pane is Iron Man, the fourth pane is Looper, and the third pane might be Avengers 2?

Comment: #1 could be ROT13(EbobPbc)

Comment: I think #3 is actually ROT13(Zrtnzvaq)

Comment: @Phylyp, I had thought about that, but the other panes appear to be actual scenes from the movies and I don't remember him lying in a bed with a sheet over him. Been a while since I saw it, though.

Comment: sorry, I think my last question is too broad, I'll update it

Comment: btw, #4 is a huge spoiler

Comment: @Nank is it? I'm pretty sure it's the premise of the whole movie.

Comment: SPOILER /!\ @IanMacDonald , for me it's the last scene of the movie where he rot13(xvyyf uvzfrys gb cerirag uvf byq frys gb xvyy gur zbz) (it was in a kind of corn field, I think that's what we see in the background)

Comment: Yeah I'm not exactly sure what the question is either, I'm fairly certain all 4 panels have been guessed. rot13(fb jr unir ebobpbc, vebazna, zrtnzvaq, ybbcre - vz guvaxvat n gvzrgeniryyvat fpvragvfg plobet cbyvprzna - gur pybfrfg v pna guvax bs vf gur grezvangbe)

Comment: there are hidden clues in my post :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is

> Superman from “Man of Steel”

Kinda stretched logic but

> Movie name is similar to “Iron man” and robocop’s body is probably made of steel. Third pane has similar plotting - aliens from other planet become hero/villain on Earth. And as for the forth pane, my guess is that cornfield kinda similar to farm where Superman was raised and where part of final clash took place.

Comment: you're on the right track! but that's not the answer I intended :) your answer must fit in "Find a similar man who's more than 1000 miles away."